# How to define molecular docking score in R to plot ROC curve using ROCR package?

Tags: r, plot, roc, auc

I trying get ROC curve and AUC value for my Molecular docking results using ROCR package in R studio.

> (About my data, X-axis: variable name is **Title** which consist the 2010 decoys name followed by screened top active 10 molecules. Y-axis variable name is  **Docking_score** value consist like this -9.321..,)

```
setwd("~/R/ROCR")
mydata<-read.csv(file ="decoys-active-dock.csv")
summary(mydata)
#attaching data the file for work
attach(mydata)
#predictions begins
library(ROCR)
pred.svm <- prediction(mydata, docking_score)
```

**Error Message:**
Number of cross-validation runs must be equal for predictions and labels in ROC Curve plot using ROCR

I need know, How to define molecular docking score for prediction in R ?

Comment: Try without using `attach()`

Comment: did, received error 
Error in is.data.frame(labels) : object 'docking_score' not found

Comment: It's difficult to help further without a reproducible example.

Comment: kindly check [mydata](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AwKjiZ2Xkq1U6J88P0F1h5v9CbQpSCza/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your data is not setup to use the `prediction()` function as intended. See the `ROCR.simple` data set made available in the package by running `data(ROCR.simple);ROCR.simple` to see what the data should look like. Run `?prediction` for more information about the function.

Comment: asking for better understanding, checked ROCR.simple which consist only two column. so  I need add one extra column in mu mydata namely labels which 0 or 1 (which is now only contain the Title and docking score) correct ? 

`> str(ROCR.simple)`
`List of 2`
`$ predictions: num [1:200] 0.613 0.364 0.432 0.14 0.385 ...`
`$ labels     : num [1:200] 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 ...`

Comment: Yes that is correct